# How does the projection-angle of road arrows change drivers' expectations of the appropriate speed in a curve?

Tags: design, user-research, physical, speed, transit

Have any studies been conducted to decide the 'print angle' ([anamorphic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphosis)) of road signage?

[image: trning angle assumptions]
[image: image-in-lane]

Are there any other expectations involved?

Comment: http://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/roadway_dept/night_visib/pavement_visib/no090488/

Comment: Part I
There are many factors affecting pavement marking legibility and the effect of the marking on driver behavior: vehicle speed, time of day, type of road, type of intersection, driver characteristics, paint type, pavement type, purpose of the marking, color of the paint, etc. [A summary of some of TTI's research on this topic.](http://d2dtl5nnlpfr0r.cloudfront.net/tti.tamu.edu/documents/researcher/ttr-v40-n1.pdf)

Comment: Part II
The pavement marking research results have been codified into guidelines for pavement marking. For example, see [section 22.2 in this document.](http://assets.dft.gov.uk/publications/traffic-signs-manual/traffic-signs-manual-chapter-05.pdf) The word SLOW appears in two sizes. The size depends on the speed limit of the road on which the marking appears.

Comment: Part III
Google 'pavement marking' legibility OR readability and you will find detailed research reports on this topic along with guidelines like the one referenced in the previous comment.

Comment: @user1757436 why did you comment instead of writing an answer?  This seems to be just along the lines of a viable answer to the question?

Comment: Thinking that people may have read this as a 'lmgtfy' question, I have re-phrased it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is an known answer to this question.

There is research on other horizontal signing as speed countermeasures in curves that attempts to use pavement marking size and spacing to lead drivers to the appropriate speed. I am unaware of research that addresses the use of arrow dimensions for the same purpose.

Starting with general information and leading toward more specific research, here are some references that might help guide you toward your own answer.

[Human Factors Guidelines for Road Systems.](http://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/nchrp/nchrp_rpt_600Second.pdf) 
See Chapter 6 on curves, speed selection in curves, and countermeasures.

[Toolbox of Countermeasures for Rural Two-Lane Curves](http://www.intrans.iastate.edu/research/documents/research-reports/Rural_2-Lane_Curves_Toolbox_w_cvr.pdf).
See pages 44 through 45

Those documents point to two experiments using arrows as pavement markings.

[The most recent](http://www.ce.siue.edu/faculty/hzhou/ww/paper/2005_FIELD%20EVALUATIONS%20AND%20DRIVER%20COMPREHENSION%20studies%20of%20horizontal%20signing_report_21.pdf) has two sections of interest.

- Starting on page 18, it provides human factors guidelines for horizontal signing.

  Page 39 describes the results for the type of arrow of interest in this question. As with the next research paper, they provide the dimensions for the horizontal signing but do not describe how they arrived at those dimensions - one would assume they are based on the guidelines on page 18.

[This research paper](http://www.ite.org/membersonly/itejournal/pdf/JIA98A30.pdf) describes an experiment evaluating the effect of an arrow preceding the entry into a curve on vehicle speed. They do not describe how they decided on the dimensions of the arrow or the word SLOW as shown in Figure 2 in the paper.

That paper referenced [this earlier research.](http://www.ktc.uky.edu/files/2012/09/1980-Transverse-Pavement-Markings-for-Speed-Control-and-Accident-Reduction-Report-No.-539.pdf) It lists the variables to consider when placing and sizing pavement markings. It is applied to stripes, rather than arrows, preceding a curve but should provide a good starting point for solving the problem.

As always, if I've missed something, please amend the answer to include it.